# iOS: create a XIB from a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, xib, nib

I have lots of Views in old projects that I have layed out in code, using absolute positioning. That code is really hard to maintain. I'd like to port the code to using interface builder, but I'd have to layout every view again by hand.

Is it possible to programmatically create a XIB file from an existing UIView (which has been created programmatically)? I have searched the docs but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XIBs are essentially XML files, I guess that if you inspect a few you'd understand the format for different controls, but that would need a lot of manual reading, writing & testing to complete for all views. Probably a better plan would be to start slowly migrating to IB-made views.

Comment: Well the thing is, I wouldn't want to end up having a couple of IB-created views here and a couple of hardcoded ones there. I'd like to have consistency. I have looked at the XML code in a XIB (didn't know it was XML) but fiddling with it doesn't look very appealing either, as it is surely faster to just layout everything in actual interface builder.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find are any tools that can help you do it automatically.

Comment: I marked the answer as accepted as there seems to be no way to port UIViews to XIBs easily. As of today, migrating by hand/over time seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible; however, the thing is, you need to set all essential controls and properties of your xib. You won't be able to see its actual look and feel unless you have executed the project in your simulator or on an actual device (that means hard code everything).

You would use **loadview** in initializing your xib. Here's a bit of it:

```
- (void)loadview{
      // set your view, screen size, and other properties of your xib
}
```

Comment: This is what I already do. My question was not how to create a view without using a XIB. It's how to create a XIB from a UIView.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused earlier. XIBs are XML files, right. So, if you have keen understanding on XML, you can actually create your XIB. However, I haven't found yet any reference on converting an objective-c code into XML. If not, you need to code it down in XML; unless if you have a current XML file in which you could copy the script and paste it to your new XIB file.